# In vue-router middleware, how to detect page reload but ignore other route changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to make it so that I run a hydration function only when the browser is reloaded, not when every route changes. For example, I have this `vue-router` middleware:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, _, next) => {
    const auth = useAuthStore();
    let isAuthenticated = false;
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
        isAuthenticated = await auth.checkAccessToken();
    }

    if (isAuthenticated) {
        const agency = useAgencyStore();
        agency.loadAgency();

        if (to.meta.redirectsWhenAuthenticated) {
            return next({ name: 'dashboard.index' });
        }

        return next();
    }

    if (!to.meta.requiresAuth) {
        return next();
    }

    toast.warning('Your session has expired.');
    return next({ name: 'login' });
});
```

I'm trying to add logic into it where it will have an additional if statement, such as:

```
if (page was just reloaded) {
    agency.loadAgency();
}
```

Right now the above logic fires every time the route changes, such as even when the query strings change, so it's spamming my backend a bit. I want to make it so normal route changes don't fire `agency.loadAgency();` only when the page is hard reloaded such as pressing F5.

I had code like this in an old app I made, so I'm pretty sure it's possible. Something like:

```
const START_LOCATION = from.fullPath;

if (!START_LOCATION) {
    // perform reload logic
}
```

I'm open to alternate ideas such as hydrating the app in App.vue created lifecycle. Any help is appreciated.

Additional info:

- Vue 3 with Vite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent any routing before some async data (in Vuex store) has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495461/how-to-prevent-any-routing-before-some-async-data-in-vuex-store-has-loaded)

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer here is to use vue-router `START_LOCATION` in the middleware. Here is an example:

```
import { START_LOCATION } from 'vue-router';

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    if (from === START_LOCATION) {
        console.log('this fires on page reload only, not every route change');
    }
});
```

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#start-location